# Instagram API sandbox - display by hashtags

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to develop an Instagram feed based off one hashtag for a website.  This hashtag only needs to be searched on one Instagram account.  I have been trying the following endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/christielakecamp/media/recent?access_token=xxxxxx&count=9
```

.. but I get the following error back:

```
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}
```

My "app" is currently in sandbox mode, and I've read that I need access to the "public_content" permission in order to do this.  When I go to submit my app for review I select what I want to do with it:

> I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website.

I get this back:

> This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).

Does this mean that I can't display info from my own feed based on hashtags?

Answer (score 0):

You can display hashtags from your own account, you have to use the `access_token` from your account and you dont need `public_content` permission if its only your content you need.

Comment: Well that's great.  How do I go about that though?  I can't seem to find any endpoint under "/user" which allows for it.

Comment: is the user post u want the same user you are logging in as ? do u have any posts with the hashtags? the endpoint you are using is correct

Comment: Yes the user posts come from the same user I am logging in as.  There are multiple posts with the hashtag I am trying to use.

Comment: Any ideas for how I can search by hashtag on my own account krisrak ?

Comment: I tried in my sandbox mode, called for one of my hashtag using API, it showed some results, not all, i think the hashtag has to be in the latest 20 posts.